# Angular 2 - ActivatedRoute don't carry data

Tags: angular, typescript

I followed the tutorial on the angular website and everything was fine.
However, I tried to create another project with the same patterns, but I can't pass data through ActivatedRoute.

Here's the code :

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { LevelService } from './level.service';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { LevelComponent } from './level.component';
import { SelectorComponent } from './selector.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/selector',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'selector',
        component: SelectorComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'level/:id',
        component: LevelComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, SelectorComponent, LevelComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ LevelService ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'My App';
}
```

selector.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Level } from './level';
import { LevelComponent } from './level.component';
import { LevelService } from './level.service';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-selector',
  template:`
    <h3>Selector</h3>
    <a *ngFor="let level of levels"  (click)="gotoLevel(level)">
      <div>
        <h4>Level : {{level.id}}</h4>
      </div>
    </a>
  `
})

export class SelectorComponent implements OnInit {
  levels: Level[];

  constructor (private router: Router, private levelService: LevelService) {}

  getLevels(): void {
    this.levelService.getLevels().then(levels => this.levels = levels);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getLevels();
  }

  gotoLevel(level: Level): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/level', level.id]);
  }

}
```

level.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Level } from './level';
import { LEVELS } from './mock-levels';

@Injectable()
export class LevelService {
  getLevels(): Promise<Level[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(LEVELS);
  }

  getLevel(id: number): Promise<Level> {
    return this.getLevels().then(levels => levels.find(level => level.id === id));
  }
}
```

level.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Level } from './level';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { LevelService } from './level.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-level',
  template: `
  <h3>Level {{level.id}}<h3>
  <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
  `
})

export class LevelComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input()
  level: Level;
  constructor (private levelService: LevelService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private location: Location){}
  ngOnInit():void {
    this.route.params.switchMap((params: Params) => this.levelService.getLevel(+params['id'])).subscribe(level => this.level = level);
  }
  goBack():void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

level.ts

```
export class Level {
  id: number;
}
```

mock-levels.ts

```
import { Level } from './level';

export const LEVELS: Level[] = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3},
  {id: 4},
  {id: 5},
  {id: 6},
];
```

Comment: My bad, it seems I was a bit too fast on this one. Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine, the only reason I could think of is that change detection may not be kicking in. Try changing your template like this to ensure after you get your level object that the template is rendered:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-level',
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="level">
    <h3>Level {{level?.id}}<h3>
    <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
  </div>
  `
})
export class LevelComponent implements OnInit{
```

Comment: It worked ! Thanks :D Unfortunately, my vote is not displayed as I do not have a big reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActivatedRoute and Router like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router ,ActivatedRoute  } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub-cat',
  templateUrl: './sub-cat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sub-cat.component.css']
})
export class SubCatComponent {
  public category={};
  constructor( private route:ActivatedRoute  ,private router:Router ){
  }
  onClickCategory(item){
    this.router.navigate(['shipping-details', {data: item.id}]);
    sessionStorage.setItem(item.id, JSON.stringify(item));
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.category =JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(this.route.snapshot.params['data']));
  }

}
```